# exceptions in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

В JavaScript есть checked и unchecked exception-ы ? И как настроен иерархия?

```
Throwable-exception error-checked unchecked?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В JavaScript нет checked и unchecked exception-ы они есть в Java.
Я думаю тут речь идет об ошибках которые можно отловить в `try catch` и нельзя.
Но следуя аналогии ошибки в JavaScript делятся на 3 типа. Подробнее [тут](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/javascript_error_handling.htm#:%7E:text=There%20are%20three%20types%20of,and%20(c)%20Logical%20Errors.)

1. Syntax Errors - синтаксические или parsing errors

```js
<!--
    window.print(;
//-->
```

Когда происходит данная ошибка, то это касается только текущего потока выполнения, прочие будут работать как задумано.
Данную ошибку вы не сможете отловить в `try catch`

```js
try {
window.print(;
} catch (e) {
 console.log("не отловили");
}
```

2. Runtime Errors - ошибки во время выполнения, они также называются exceptions, возникаю после компиляции или интерпретации.
   следующий пример демонстрирует ошибку во время выполнения (не существует метода) так как синтаксически ту все верно.

```js
<!--
      window.printme();
//-->
```

Исключения также влияют на поток, в котором они возникают, позволяя другим потокам JavaScript продолжать нормальное выполнение.
Данную ошибку вы сможете отловить в `try catch`

```js
try {
  window.printme();
} catch (e) {
 console.log("отловили");
}
```

3. Logical Errors

Логические ошибки могут быть наиболее трудным для отслеживания типом ошибок. Эти ошибки не являются Syntax Error или Runtime Error. Вместо этого они возникают, когда вы ошибаетесь в логике, управляющей сценарием, и не получаете ожидаемого результата.

Вы не можете отловить эти ошибки, потому что от зависит требований вашего бизнеса, какой тип логики вы хотите добавить в свою программу.

Comment: Можно добавить что все стандартные ошибки наследуются от глобального объекта [Error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error), но кидать (throw) можно что угодно. `try { throw 42 } catch(e) { console.log(e /* === 42 */) }`

Comment: Да, спасибо, Алексей. Хотел добавить, но не видел смысла такого же как в Java.